# Putting App Shortcuts on Desktop?

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gnome-shell, shortcuts

Let's say that I wanted to put Rhythmbox on my desktop and not on my dock. How can I do this? I am on Ubuntu 17.10 with the GNOME Desktop. I already have desktop icons on in the Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple `.desktop` (say `rhythmbox.desktop`) file in Desktop with content like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Any comment you like
Terminal=false
Name=Rhythmbox
Exec=path/to/Rhythmbox/binary
Type=Application
Icon=path/to/Rhythmbox/icon
NoDisplay=false
```

You can use `Exec=rhythmbox %U`, `Icon=rhythmbox` in case of Rhythmbox in particular.

Alternatively, you may copy the intended `.desktop` file to Desktop from `/usr/share/applications/`.

Then right click on the `.desktop` file and check "Allow executing file as program" under *Permissions*.

Comment: Rhythmbox has its own .desktop file, no need to create another.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ah, yes! I added that too.